# Do these sentences have same meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference

There are two sentences below.

1. I never want to see you hurt again.
2. I never want to see you that hurt again.

Do these sentence have same meaning? If the meaning is different, please tell me the difference.

Answer (score 0):

*That* before an adjective means "to that degree", or "as much as that". It means pretty much the same as *so*, but it's more informal.

So in principle, the second sentence could mean "I don't mind seeing you hurt a bit, but I don't want to see you hurt that much", which is different from the first sentence.

In practice, it's hard to imagine anybody saying it with that meaning, so there's no difference.

**Edited** as I got the first and second the wrong way round.